# server ip keeps redirecting to defaultwebpage.cgi

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I haven't registered any domain for my server.
I might be wrong, but according to my understanding,
the default ip for the server is public.
my server ip is http://166.62.101.242/.
but whenever i ping on that domain, it keeps redirecting to the `/usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi`
folder.
I have changed my `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html
  <Directory /var/www/html/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

however it still keeps redirecting to the cpanel page.
what changes do i need to make, so i can access the `/var/www` folder without registering for a domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This redirection is because `cPanel` uses Block Hosting. You will have to point a domain to the IP Address and tell `cPanel` to register that domain in your system. I would highly suggest you to get a domain instead of modifying anything with `cPanel` because if something goes wrong, you may not be able to manage your site. You can get a free domain from [`freenom.com`](https://freenom.com). If you need further assistance for setting it up, please hit me up and I'll guide you step by step.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is error in processing .php file in apache.
I have got same problem.
change the ownership of the file.
e.g. if the file name ins info.php

```
sudo chown nobody:nobody info.php
sudo chmod 644 info.php
```

Let me know if this help

Also make sure to add .php in

```
sudo vim /etc/httpd/apache/conf

AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .php5 .php4 .php .php3 .php2 .phtml .php
```

Comment: mention the path to the info.php,

Comment: also, you didnot need to create any virtual host?

Comment: @SouparnoMajumder the default web root of apache is /etc/apache/htdocks

Comment: @SouparnoMajumder You can change the default virtual host in /etc/apache/conf/http.conf or can create your own. Follow this link https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-centos-6

Comment: Which log file got you to this conclusion? What was the error!

Answer (score 0):

It is looks that you have VPS with a WHM/cPanel.
There are multiple possibilities to set that.
The most easy way is to add an account and set a new domain...
Or can hack the Apache global configuration WHM -> ApacheConfiguration -> Global Configuration and set a new virtual server in premain. The server should have same external and internal IPs
The other way is to hack the main.conf template and change the httpd configuration.
After, you should run:

```
/services/rebuildhttpdconf
```

to rebuild the httpd.conf

Please note that your changes in default httpd.conf will be overwrite everytime the cPanel/WHM will restart, so your solution with modification of default /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf it is not OK!

Answer (score 0):

Try with the IP instead...

VirtualHost 166.62.101.242:80

...and clean your browser cache! (or you can try this first).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same behavior and I was going to hit my head to the wall because of that :(.  The reason why you are getting this is because the content of `/etc/httpd/htdocs/index.html` IS

```
<html><head><META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="0;URL=/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi"></head><body></b‌​ody></html>
```

It takes 2 days for me to figure this out. If you managed to land your request on your server but the name you are requesting -the IP in our case- is not exist in the apache virtual hosts, the apache is going to response with this file. ;-)